# Is it possible to save JS objects into a Sqlite database?

Tags: node.js, json, sqlite

I have a node server that receives a user input from the browser, and passes it through a python script that outputs an object.

My question is, is it possible to then take this object and save it to an sqlite table? Not with its key/value pairs as rows/columns etc. but the whole object as a single entry? 
I was thinking of converting into a string and then doing this but I'm not sure if this is the best approach.

Any help relating to the issue would be great.

Comment: That's probably the only option. [SQLite has a very simple type system](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html). Only TEXT and BLOB could store complex data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you intend, but you could simply stringify your JSON and then put it into your table